Derive elliptic maximum principle from weak derivatives
Let $U$ is a connected open set, and $a^{ij}, c^i \in L^\infty (U).$ $a^{ij}$ satisfies the uniform ellipticity condition. Suppose that $u\in H^1(U) \cap C(\overline U)$ satisfies the condition that
$$
\int a^{ij} \partial_i\varphi \partial_j u  + \varphi c^i \partial_i u \leq 0, 
$$
for every nonnegative $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(U).$ I am trying to generalise the elliptic weak maximum principle to weak solutions by proving that this implies $\sup_{U} u = \sup_{\partial U} u.$
However, I find this hard. In the literature, the maximum principle is often proven for $C^2$ functions. We can, of course, take a sequence of $C^2$ functions $u_j$ which converges to $u$ in $H^1$ and $C(\overline U).$
But then the above integral condition may not be satisfied for $u_j.$ We can add $Ce^{\gamma x_1}$ to $u_j$ to correct this, but it is not obvious that such correction converges to $0$ as $j\to \infty.$
Also, I wish I could do this directly instead of resorting to the smooth case.

This is not a complete answer.
Since $u-\sup_{\partial U} u$ solves the same inequation, w.l.o.g. you can assume that $ u\leq 0$ on $\partial U$ and you want to prove $u\leq 0$ inside.
By density your inequation extends to any non-negative  $\varphi \in H^1_0(\Omega)$. Now, the function $u^+$ (positive part) of $u$ is in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ and you can use it as a test function. You have that $\partial_i u^+ = \mathbf{1}_{u>0} \partial_i u$ so
$$ \int a^{ij} \partial_i u^+ \partial_j u^+ +  u^+ c^i \partial_i u^+ \leq 0.$$
Using Poincaré's inequality and the implicit ellipticity assumption $(a^{ij})_{ij}\geq \alpha Id$ for some $\alpha>0$ you get
\begin{align*}
\alpha \|\nabla u^+\|_2^2 \leq C_U \|c\|_\infty \|\nabla u^+\|_2^2,
\end{align*}
where $C_U$ is the Poincaré constant on $U$. This solves the question at least in the case when $C_U \|c\|_\infty<\alpha$ : you then have $u^+=0$. For the general case I wonder if dilatations $u(\lambda x)$ can allow you to take $\|c\|_\infty$ as small as you need but I'm afraid this will also affect the Poincaré constant. Also, when $c$ is constant the integral of $u^+\partial_i u^+$ vanishes because $u^+$ is $H^1_0(\Omega)$, I am almost sure you should be able to teduce to this case using that $c$ is bounded.
